# Implementing redirect in Redux middleware

Tags: redirect, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

Let's say I have following action:

```
export function signIn(data) {
  return {
    type: USER_SIGN_IN,
    promise: api.post('/sign_in', data)
  }
}
```

and following middleware:

```
export default function promiseMiddleware() {
  return next => action => {
    const { promise, type, ...rest } = action

    if (!promise) {
      return next(action)
    }

    const SUCCESS = `${type}_SUCCESS`
    const REQUEST = `${type}_REQUEST`
    const ERROR = `${type}_ERROR`

    next({ type: REQUEST, ...rest })

    return promise
      .then(res => {
        next({ response: res.data, type: SUCCESS, ...rest })
        return true
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ...
      })
  }
}
```

This code is loosely based on https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/

**But what if in `then` callback after calling `next` I want to make a redirect to another path?**

I did following. I passed redirect url through action:

```
export function signIn(data) {
  return {
    type: USER_SIGN_IN,
    promise: api.post('/sign_in', data),
    redirect: '/'
  }
}
```

and added another call of `next` method with `push` from `react-router-redux`.

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

export default function promiseMiddleware() {
  return next => action => {
    const { promise, type, redirect, ...rest } = action
    ...
    return promise
      .then(res => {
        next({ response: res.data, type: SUCCESS, ...rest })
        next(push(redirect))
        return true
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ...
      })
  }
}
```

It seems like it works, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea or if there are some pitfalls of multiple `next` calls and I shouldn't do like this?

Maybe there are some better approaches for implementing such redirects?

Comment: seems to be ok, but you better copy paste your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes, copy it to the codereview, and add a link, I think you could do it better with `redux-thunk`

Comment: @webdeb thanks, I created a question there - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138296/implementing-redirect-in-redux-middleware